# ms access query - Filter out values from another query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a query running that pulls out the records I need.
I want to run another query that pulls out all the other records (excluding the ones in the first query).
I've read up on NOT IN and NOT LIKE but can't seem to get them to work.

The first query is named: qryHunnersPatients

Here's the code for the second query that I have so far:

Right now this is just pulling all the records - but I want to exclude those records in the qryHunnersPatients query

```
SELECT 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID, 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.Age, 
    [tblPatientHistoryBaseline].[Age]-[tblPatientHistoryBaseline].[UrinarySxBegan] AS Duration, 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.IBS, 
    tblQuestionnaires.UPOINTTotal, 
    tblQuestionnaires.U, 
    tblQuestionnaires.P, 
    tblQuestionnaires.O, 
    tblQuestionnaires.I, 
    tblQuestionnaires.N, 
    tblQuestionnaires.T, 
    tblQuestionnaires.ICSITotal, 
    tblQuestionnaires.ICPITotal
FROM 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline 
    INNER JOIN 
    tblQuestionnaires 
    ON 
    (tblPatientHistoryBaseline.Visit = tblQuestionnaires.Visit) 
    AND 
    (tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID = tblQuestionnaires.ID);
```

---

UPDATE:
I just tried the WHERE NOT EXISTS using the code below:

```
SELECT 
        tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID, 
        tblPatientHistoryBaseline.Age, 
        [tblPatientHistoryBaseline].[Age]-[tblPatientHistoryBaseline].[UrinarySxBegan] AS Duration, 
        tblPatientHistoryBaseline.IBS, 
        tblQuestionnaires.UPOINTTotal, 
        tblQuestionnaires.U, 
        tblQuestionnaires.P, 
        tblQuestionnaires.O, 
        tblQuestionnaires.I, 
        tblQuestionnaires.N, 
        tblQuestionnaires.T, 
        tblQuestionnaires.ICSITotal, 
        tblQuestionnaires.ICPITotal
    FROM 
        tblPatientHistoryBaseline 
        INNER JOIN 
        tblQuestionnaires 
        ON 
        (tblPatientHistoryBaseline.Visit = tblQuestionnaires.Visit) 
        AND 
        (tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID = tblQuestionnaires.ID)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT ID
             FROM qryHunnersPatients AS hunners
             WHERE hunners.ID = tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SubQuery. As In understand that your Query `qryHunnersPatients` gives you the list of records that you do not wish to see, you need to include that in the **NOT IN** part of the Query.

```
SELECT 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID, 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.Age, 
    [tblPatientHistoryBaseline].[Age]-[tblPatientHistoryBaseline].[UrinarySxBegan] AS Duration, 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.IBS, 
    tblQuestionnaires.UPOINTTotal, 
    tblQuestionnaires.U, 
    tblQuestionnaires.P, 
    tblQuestionnaires.O, 
    tblQuestionnaires.I, 
    tblQuestionnaires.N, 
    tblQuestionnaires.T, 
    tblQuestionnaires.ICSITotal, 
    tblQuestionnaires.ICPITotal
FROM 
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline 
    INNER JOIN 
    tblQuestionnaires 
    ON 
    (tblPatientHistoryBaseline.Visit = tblQuestionnaires.Visit) 
    AND 
    (tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID = tblQuestionnaires.ID)
WHERE
    tblPatientHistoryBaseline.ID 
    NOT IN 
    (SELECT qryHunnersPatients.ID FROM qryHunnersPatients);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ID` is unique, you can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT {FieldList}
FROM tblPatientHistoryBaseline AS baseline
INNER JOIN tblQuestionnaires AS quest
  ON (baseline.Visit = quest.Visit) 
    AND (baseline.ID = quest.ID);    
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT ID
  FROM qryHunnersPatients AS hunners
  WHERE hunners.ID = baseline.ID
)
```

You don't need to bother using the aliases I've added to; I've just added them for readability.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The ID is unique - I added the WHERE NOT EXISTS but now the query is returning nothing.
I've added the updated code to the bottom of the post.